# #spring boot #Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am Trying to build MVC application but getting issues which correspond Network Error:

"NetworkError: 401 Unauthorized - http://localhost:8080/SpringBootCRUDApp/api/user/"

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/SpringBootCRUDApp/api/user/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

```html
`
[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: you should use `@CrossOrigin` on your endpoints as stated in the documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-cors

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your Application.java (i.e) Where you have loaded your App Context.

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/greeting-javaconfig").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8080");
        }
    };
}
```

Just replace the addMapping part with your own api.
It just adds the particular origin (i.e) localhost:8080.
If you want to allow all ports, you must use a wild card "*" in allowedOrigins.
For More Info : [Refer](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/%20Reference)

Comment: Just edit your question and add your code for controller and the SpringBootApplication.